# TSQL If Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script where I am allowing for a user to generate a report. They choose options and one of those drop downs is Location. It contains a list of places and the very first option is "ALL".

When you select all, I would like to have it include anything thats in the location column.

Here is my current statement.

```
IF (@action = 'searchActivityLog')
        IF (@type = 'actor')
            BEGIN
                SELECT  actor,
                        action,
                        CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), timestamp, 100) AS timestamp,
                        [key],
                        location
                FROM   Keys_Log
                WHERE  actor = @data AND location = @location
                ORDER BY timestamp asc
                FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
            END
        ELSE
```

Is there a way to basically say if Location = All then dont even include that in the where clause?

Comment: Please see my answer below. I hope, it should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you just include

```
location = @location OR @location = 'All'
```

In the where clause.

The only other option would be Dynamics SQL - but this makes things more complicated. See

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/ for examples.

Comment: Location will never be all though, its actual place names in the column. I wont have a record in there called all.

Comment: The you could pass NULL to the stored proc to represent all locations and use OR @location IS NULL

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.. My col called location contains "All, Arizona, California, Texas".

My statement is saying "Select * where location = 'Arizona'

Location is never going to be NULL or contain the word All, i just want to include it no matter what is in the col if "All" is selected

Comment: I think this solution works, just put parentheses around the clause. It will return a a row if the location field matches the location parameter, or if the location parameter is All, it will always return that row.

Comment: Okay, this worked:

IF (@location = 'All') SET @location = NULL

`WHERE  (actor = @data AND location = @location OR @location IS NULL)`

Thank you!

Comment: Never mind, it seems that when ALL is selected, it ignores the first part of the where statement (the actor) and includes everything

Comment: Works, moved the ()

`WHERE actor = @data AND (location = @location OR @location IS NULL)`